# Equal Space Between Table Headers

Tags: html, html-table, navbar, dreamweaver

I am currently creating a practice website for my Arma 2 Unit (88th Airborne Divsion), I have created a simple navigation bar using table headers hyperlinked, however the space between the table headers is dependant on how long the word is. Is there a way of making equal space between the headers?

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>88th Airborne Division</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner"><img src="images/logo.png" width="680" height="125" alt="logo" /></div>
  <div id="navbar"><table width="680" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Home</th>
    <th>About Us</th>
    <th>Members</th>
    <th>Apply</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
*{
    margin:0;


    }

#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#banner {
    height: 125px;
    width: 680px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}


#navbar {
    background-color:#333;
    width: 680px;
    height:25px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
th{
    border-right-width:medium;
    border-right-color:#000;
    border-right-style:groove;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Notice how Home is smaller than about us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `table width=680`, you can put in CSS`tr{ width: 170px; }`, or, you can change `th` in CSS

```
tr{  
    position: relative; /* you may put it out, maybe it will work without it */
}

th{
    border-right-width:medium;
    border-right-color:#000;
    border-right-style:groove;
    width: 25%;
}
```

which gives you more flexible sizing. Also, I don't know if you have any additional borders or margins. If so, `td`s will not fit in that 25% (because dimension is measured without margin, padding and border), so play with it (lower percentage until you get the right look).